# How to change a variable in a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json

I need to change a `state` in my json file,
I must do a game with HTML and javascript in my json i have players with attributes like name,password and state.

My request only needs to looks at the number `state` points to, and changes it if it must.

How can I write code that changes only `player.state`, from  1 to 3?

This is the JSON file

```
[
    {"pseudo":"player1","password":"player","state":"1"},
    {"pseudo":"player2","password":"player","state":"0"}
]
```

Comment: Well-formed questions on this site are of the form:
"I'm trying to do X"
"I have tried A, B, C and get <error meesage>| <invalid result> | <other undesired result>" 
"Here is the code I'm using:"

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows:

```js
function changeState(playersArray,playerToChange,newState){
     playersArray.find(function(player) {return player.pseudo == playerToChange}).state = newState;
}

var players = [
    {"pseudo":"player1","password":"player","state":"1"},
    {"pseudo":"player2","password":"player","state":"0"}
]

changeState(players,"player2",3);
```